# How to get grep consider any character as regular

Tags: linux, string, bash, sed, grep

I am trying grep some string in a script.
I don't know what string i am finding or what is in file where I am trying to find it. I just need grep **exact** string from file.

So, my problem is, sometimes greping string contains square brackets and as I found out, grep consider them special characters.

```
string='some [text]'
grep "$string" file
```

I can escape them with sed

```
string='some [text]'
grep "$(sed -e 's/\[/\\[/g' <<< "$string")" file
```

I need grep to match exact string no matter what input can be. So is there a nicer way to do it? some way to tell grep to consider every character in string as regular character? If no, are there any other special characters like [ I need to worry about?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `-F` option, to interpret it as fixed string:

```
grep -F "$string" file
```